# php and apache together in docker

Tags: php, apache, docker

first of all i pulled apache image:

`docker pull httpd`

then i ran my apache on `8080` port

`docker run -dit --name httpd -p 8080:80 -v "$PWD":/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd`

i opened `127.0.0.1:8080` and it is ok
i have a file named `info.php` and it exists in `PWD` and when i open it in my browser i see php code and it had not been compiled

how can it use php and apache together in docker and how i am able to run php in my browser

im new comer to docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this image `php:<version>-apache`

**php:-apache**

> This image contains Debian's Apache httpd in conjunction with PHP (as
> mod_php) and uses mpm_prefork by default.

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name my-apache-php-app -v "$PWD":/var/www/html php:7.2-apache
```

Or you can copy PHP files at build times.

Tree

```
├── Dockerfile
└── src
    └── info.php
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

Run container

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name my-apache-php-app my_image
```